# Gson can't parse a string json format data in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, gson, kotlin

I'm writing an app in Kotlin. I have a raw JSON string coming from a webservice and I need to use it with Gson.

I'm doing this:

```
val gson = Gson()
val friends = gson.fromJson(response.rawResponse, JsonElement::class)
```

but the compiler can't find the correct `fromJson` method overload, which is currently available instead (`fromJson(json: String!, typeOfT: Type!)`).

That's the error:

```
Error:(65, 50) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: JsonElement!, classOfT: Class<JsonElement!>!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: JsonElement!, typeOfT: Type!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(reader: JsonReader!, typeOfT: Type!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: Reader!, classOfT: Class<JsonElement!>!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: Reader!, typeOfT: Type!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: String!, classOfT: Class<JsonElement!>!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
public open fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: String!, typeOfT: Type!): JsonElement! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should pass a `java.lang.Class` rather than a `kotlin.reflect.KClass`, for example:

```
val friends = gson.fromJson(response.rawResponse, JsonElement::class.java)
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you so much! I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @NicolaGiancecchi Not at all. It is my pleasure, :)